# An Englishman Playing 'Ell With the Great Lakes!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

Who is identified by the following verse?

> I'm known for words I never said
>   And gear that seldom graced my head.
>   Of siblings I am not most smart.
>   A doctor said I'm cold of heart.
>   Amused by bows and flower juices,
>   I am convinced between two sluices.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you're

> Sherlock Holmes

I'm known for words I never said

> He never said "Elementary, my dear Watson" in the stories

And gear that seldom graced my head.

> His 'signature' deerstalker hat isn't something he wore in the stories. OP: I considered saying “never” instead of “seldom”. The term deerstalker is never used but in one story he wears a hat with ear flaps which could well be a deerstalker. At any rate it wasn’t normal headgear for him.

Of siblings I am not most smart.

> His brother Mycroft is depicted as smarter

A doctor said I'm cold of heart.

> Dr. Watson tends to feel that Sherlock is somewhat cold and lacking emotion - @Tom got this first

Amused by bows and flower juices,

> He plays the violin (bow) and he has a fond relationship with drugs, namely opium (from poppies) - thanks @Tom and @psmears

I am convinced between two sluices.

> I am **sure** in a **lock**.  Sherlock.

Title:

> Sherlock Holmes is an Englishman.  There is an acronym for the great lakes: HOMES.  Add an "ell" and you get HOLMES.

Comment: "Flower juices" - Holmes occasionally uses morphine (derived from poppies).

Comment: Thanks @psmears.  I completely spaced on that until I saw Tom's answer and your comment.

Comment: Correct! I saw your answer and Tom’s at the same time. I’m giving you the tick since yours shows first. Congrats!

Answer (score 12):

Who is identified by the following verse?

> Sherlock Holmes

I'm known for words I never said

> Sherlock Holmes never said "Elementary, my dear Watson" in any of Conan Doyle's stories.

And gear that seldom graced my head.

> Holmes is never actually described as wearing a deerstalker by Conan Doyle.

Of siblings I am not most smart.

> Mycroft Holmes who has deductive powers exceeding even Sherlock's.

A doctor said I'm cold of heart.

> Doctor Watson accusing Holmes of being without normal feelings.

Amused by bows and flower juices,

> Sherlock plays the violin and was acquainted with belladona, cocaine, morphine and opium.

I am convinced between two sluices.

> Sure Lock Holmes, and I haven't deduced this dammit.

Title: An Englishman Playing 'Ell With the Great Lakes!

> **H**uron, **O**ntario, **'L'**, **M**ichigan, **E**rie, **S**uperior

Comment: Barely beat you in submitting, but you got a couple clues I missed (how did I forget the drugs?!?).  Nice work!

Comment: Well done hagfy, you post was surely ahead and nice work from OP, this was fun.

Comment: Thanks @Tom.  Somehow forgot to add that I feel Tom should definitely get credit for this one.  He absolutely answered more completely than I did.

Comment: @hagfy, that is so generous of you, but our posts are really similar and I didn't understand the last line was solved until I saw your answer. Definitely I deduce your answer resolved this and being first would like that one to be accepted!

Comment: Nice work once again! You always seem to know wat’s on my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Lake Huron?

I'm known for words I never said

> Like the Huron Carol, which definitely wasn't written in English when it was first written by the Huron.

And gear that seldom graced my head.

> Or traditional Native headdresses which were only worn on special occasions.

Of siblings I am not most smart.

> Maybe this refers to another of the Great Lakes being *Superior* (ha ha).

A doctor said I'm cold of heart.

> Lake Huron is pretty chilly, especially at its centre/deepest points.

Amused by bows and flower juices,

> Hurons used bows (and possibly drank flower juices, I'm not sure)

I am convinced between two sluices.

> Sluices refer to water containment...

Title:

> Great Lakes, and 'Ell is missing the H (in Huron?)

Comment: Not Lake Huron. A better fit for the clues is needed. Good luck!

Comment: Am I even close?

Comment: Not really, I’m afraid.